# Space dimension of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've been searching but I can't find the solution of matrix, only  vectors.

What's the dimension space of $2 \times 2$ matrices? Find a base to this space. Then, do the same to $n \times n$ matrices.

The problem is that I can't find without the matrix.

Comment: Use the definition of a basis as a linearly independent set that spans the set. Forget the equivalent conditions to check on matrices of vectors, it can be made to work, but it's a little messy.

Comment: Matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ span the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices if $$x_1A_1+\cdots+x_nA_n=M$$ has a solution for all $M$ a $2\times 2$  matrix

Comment: $n\times n$ matrices $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are linearly independent if $$x_1A_1+\cdots+x_nA_n=Z$$ has a only the trivial solution ($x_i=0$ for all i) where $Z$ is the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix

Comment: thank you guys! I am solving this right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices under addition over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is 4 dimensional.  It's $$\operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}.$$  These are clearly independent under addition.  Can you generalize?

Comment: Thank you guys! So is this really the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1=(1,0,0,...,0)^T$,$ e_2= (0,1,0,0,...,0)^T$, etc, then the matrices $e_i e_j^T$ with 
$i,j = 1,...,n$ form a basis for the $n \times n$ matrices.

It is straightforward to check that $A = \sum_{ij} [A]_{ij} e_i e_j^T$ and
that $A = 0$ **iff** $[A]_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: @hardmath: I seem to have omitted part of my answer.

Comment: It should, but I am away from my computer. It's odd, some edits I made immediately after adding the above have disappeared.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks. Just fixed it, it was bugging me.

Comment: Thank you guys! So is this really the answer?

Comment: Both are reasonable answers. But you should only accept one if it answers the question for you.